# jsonwebtoken in apex or lightning component

Tags: apex, jwt, encoding

I need to generate a jwt with encode jsons, with this estructure:
header.payload.signature

- Header (encodeBase64)
- Payload (encodeBase64)
- Signature (encodeBase64(RSASHA256(Header+Payload)))

`String publicKey = 'MyPublicKey';`

`String jwtHeader = '{"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256"}';`

```
String payload = '{"userId": "MyUser","created": "2019-10-08T06:14:50.225Z","iat": "1570083290"}';

String jwtRequest = System.encodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(jwtHeader)) + '.' + System.encodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(payload));
system.debug('jwtRequest: ' + jwtRequest );

String signature = System.encodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.sign('RSA-SHA256', Blob.valueOf(jwtRequest), Blob.valueOf(publicKey )));
system.debug('jwt : ' + jwtRequest + '.' + signature );
```

I cannot execute the function "Crypto.sign", an error appears: 
***System.SecurityException: Invalid Crypto Key
STACKTRACE: Class.System.Crypto.sign***

I could execute by apex or js. I have a example in node.js, but I can't execute it in js:

```
const signOptions = {
    algorithm: 'RS256',
  };
  const verifyOptions = {
    algorithms: [ 'RS256' ],
  };

  const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
  const utilJwt = {
    sign: function*(val) {
      const token = yield jwt.sign(val, privateKey, signOptions);
      return token;
    },
    verify: function*(token) {
      const decoded = yield jwt.verifyAsync(token, publicKey, verifyOptions);
      return decoded;
    },
  };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your privateKey —what you have named "publicKey"— needs to be in PKCS #8 format.

**Working Sample**

In your code, if you use this sample PKCS #8 compliant key
you should get a success message:

```
String publicKey = 'MIIBVgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAUAwggE8AgEAAkEAq7BFUpkGp3+LQmlQ'
+'Yx2eqzDV+xeG8kx/sQFV18S5JhzGeIJNA72wSeukEPojtqUyX2J0CciPBh7eqclQ'
+'2zpAswIDAQABAkAgisq4+zRdrzkwH1ITV1vpytnkO/NiHcnePQiOW0VUybPyHoGM'
+'/jf75C5xET7ZQpBe5kx5VHsPZj0CBb3b+wSRAiEA2mPWCBytosIU/ODRfq6EiV04'
+'lt6waE7I2uSPqIC20LcCIQDJQYIHQII+3YaPqyhGgqMexuuuGx+lDKD6/Fu/JwPb'
+'5QIhAKthiYcYKlL9h8bjDsQhZDUACPasjzdsDEdq8inDyLOFAiEAmCr/tZwA3qeA'
+'ZoBzI10DGPIuoKXBd3nk/eBxPkaxlEECIQCNymjsoI7GldtujVnr1qT+3yedLfHK'
+'srDVjIT3LsvTqw==';
```

[Here's a useful guide to using the Crypto Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class)

[Here's the Wikipedia page where I got the sample PKCS #8 compliant key from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_8)

Comment: Needless to say, you should generate your own PKCS #8 compliant key and DO NOT use the sample one :)

Comment: The public key of my code is a random key, not the real public key. @Ideasforce, with this key the same error still appears. Do you have to activate something to use this function?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention you need to change {Blob.valueOf(publicKey)} for {EncodingUtil.base64Decode(publicKey)} with that and the sample key provided you should succeed

Comment: Ouu yeahh, perfect. Its works very well